# JQuery Mobile - Have input and label on the same line inside table, regardless of screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile. I want to have a label and an input on the same line inside a table cell. The table and the cell have fixed widths and so, I would think, that the layout inside the cell would be independent of the window width.  But, if I use the code in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1k2mds31/2/) and make the result window narrow, the label and the input are displayed on different lines and if I make the result window wide, they are displayed on the same line.  This seems odd, because the cell width is not changing when I change the size of the result window.  Any thoughts on what is going on and how to display them on the same line, even when the window is narrow?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="cost1">$</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cost1" id="cost1" value=""/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="cost2">$</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cost2" id="cost2" value=""/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    width: 10em;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 20em;
}
```

Btw... I have seen similar question on SO and elsewhere, but I am not sure what is the essential piece that will allow these to be on the same line in a variety of scenarios.  In my case, I am ultimately going to have the "$" display or not based on some javascript and want the input to resize accordingly based on the remaining space available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because that is the default behavior of `fieldcontain`. If you use your console to watch CSS changes when the media queries are hit, you'll see things happening. You could create your own class for these containers, or put in overrides in your CSS:

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ks7201ov/

```
.ui-field-contain>label {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
.ui-field-contain>label~[class*=ui-] {
    float: left;
    width: 78%;
}
.ui-field-contain:before, .ui-field-contain:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.ui-field-contain {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

A custom class may be better since the override approach can sometimes be troublesome (notice that the narrow version label of the fiddle jumps up).

Comment: Both the answers given so far will probably work for my needs.  I am evaluating them to see which I will go with.

Comment: This one answers the why piece, so I am choosing it.  Both work.  I have actually solved this in a different way.  http://jsfiddle.net/1k2mds31/10/

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise Creative has given a good answer. As an alternative, if you are using a table anyway, why not get rid of the fieldcontain and just use 4 table cells instead of 2?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelcell"><label for="cost1">$</label></td>
            <td class="inputcell"><input type="text" name="cost1" id="cost1" value=""/></td>
            <td class="labelcell"><label for="cost2">$</label></td>
            <td class="inputcell"><input type="text" name="cost2" id="cost2" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 20em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border: 0.1em solid black; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td.inputcell {
    width: 9em;    
    border-left: 0;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
td.labelcell {
    width: 1em;
    border-right: 0;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1k2mds31/7/)**

Comment: Both the answers given so far will probably work for my needs.  I am evaluating them to see which I will go with.